# React UseState if else condition won't set result

Tags: arrays, reactjs, if-statement, setstate, use-state

Ok, SO trying to think of the simplest way to ask this. 
First of all, the code isn't the most beautiful. It's the 3rd thing I've ever made in react, which I started a week ago and coding maybe a little over 2 months ago.

I am making a form that takes in data, for COVID simple: `firstName, lastName, email, and risklevel`. 
The risk level is determined by the count of questions answered yes; AKA true with if-else-statements.

The count works fine - it logs the proper number based off of questions answered true. The form information works; the only thing is that this won't take my `risklevel` state and apply it based off of three conditions:

```
function ModalPopUp() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  
  const [FirstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [LastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [riskLevel, setRiskLevel] =  useState(0);
  const [dryCough, setDryCough] = useState(null);
  const [sob, setSob] = useState(null);
  const [Aches, setAches] = useState(null);
  const [soreThroat, setSoreThroat] = useState(null);
  const [headache, setHeadache] = useState(null);
  const [fatigue, setFatigue] = useState(null);
  const [exposure, setExposure] = useState(null);
  // const [age, setAge] = useState(0)
  // const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  // const [patients, SetPatients] = useState([]);
  
  const riskState = () => {
  
    let count = 0;
    if(dryCough === true) {
      count++ 
    }
    if(sob === true) {
      count++
    }
    if(Aches === true) {
      count++ 
    }
    if(soreThroat === true) {
      count++
      
    }
    if(headache === true) {
      count++
      
    }
    if(fatigue === true) {
      count++
    }
    if(exposure === true) {
      count++
    }
    if (count <= 2) {
      setRiskLevel({riskLevel: riskLevel + 1})
    }
    if (count > 2 && count <= 4) {
      setRiskLevel({riskLevel: riskLevel + 2})
    }
    
    if (count > 4) {
      setRiskLevel({riskLevel:  riskLevel + 3})
    }
    console.log(dryCough);
    console.log(count);
    console.log(riskLevel)
  }
```

Comment: Can you please try to write complete sentences? You say you are trying to ask this simply and then you go and concatenate sentences without punctuation. Why make it so hard on us to parse your question?

Comment: I do apologize, Christian, I have Dysgraphia so sometimes short becomes way too long. I write as I think causing run-on sentences and punctuation errors. I try to avoid it but it happens especially when trying to explain something I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. Much better now!

Answer (score 0):

Very likely riskLevel is an outdated value captured by the closure. Try use the callback syntax instead.

```
setRiskLevel(riskLevel => ({riskLevel: riskLevel + 1}))
```